# Splunk - LDAP Integration - AuthenticationManagerLDAP Couldn't find matching groups and UserManagerPro - LDAP Login failed / none are mapped to Splunk

Tags: authentication, ldap, monitoring, metrics, splunk

Splunk **7.0.2**

Instead of creating Splunk internal users, I'm trying to integrate LDAP in Splunk but getting the following error message (**tail -f splunkd.log**)

```
05-02-2018 23:17:08.235 +0000 ERROR AuthenticationManagerLDAP - Couldn't find matching groups for user="1122345". Search filter="(cn=CN=Nooka\5C, Chuck,OU=Users,OU=Ov)" strategy="Centrify-Based-LDAP"
05-02-2018 23:17:08.235 +0000 ERROR UserManagerPro - LDAP Login failed, could not find a valid user="1122345" on any configured servers
05-02-2018 23:17:08.236 +0000 ERROR UiAuth - user=1122345 action=login status=failure reason=user-initiated useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.ientip=137.11.121.234
```

I referred the documentation but it didn't help much.
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.0.3/Security/ConfigureLDAPwithSplunkWeb Tried some other posts here or online with various values for LDAP settings (fields etc) but still getting the error

**Snapshot of LDAP settings are:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The the User Dn in the search filter doesn't match the User Base DN configured. Users will be searched under the User Base DN if configured else from the root of the DIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I was able to solve it.

**Solution steps**: 
1) Changed the **Static member attribute** field under Group Settings to **member**
[image]

Doing that, the error (per my post) was resolved but I got **another error** but it was more like a **hint** what I had to next.

**ERROR AuthenticationManagerLDAP user X has matching LDAP groups with strategy Y, but none are mapped to Splunk**

```
05-02-2018 23:49:59.343 +0000 ERROR AuthenticationManagerLDAP - user="1122345" has matching LDAP groups with strategy="Centrify-Based-LDAP", but none are mapped to Splunk
05-02-2018 23:49:59.343 +0000 ERROR UserManagerPro - LDAP Login failed, could not find a valid user="1122345" on any configured servers
05-02-2018 23:49:59.343 +0000 ERROR UiAuth - user=1122345 action=login status=failure reason=user-initiated useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.ientip=137.11.121.234
```

2) To solve this new / above error, as it was obvious, I had to go to Splunk as **admin** or any other elevated user who can perform the following sub-steps:

a) From the top menu bar, click on **Settings** > **Access Control** *(under USERS and AUTHENTICATION)* > **Authentication Method** > **LDAP Settings** *(under External - LDAP radio button selected)* and that took me to this page

[image]

b) Click on **Map groups** *(under Actions)* > Click on the **team-group** i.e. in my case, the value listed there for the **name** of the LDAP group *(under LDAP Group Name)* header.

That took me to this page, where you can double click on the available  **inbuilt** or *custom created* **roles** (in Splunk) from the left "Available Roles" box to copy them to the right side box "Selected Roles" and click **Save**. 
**PS**: I granted both "user" and "power" role to the LDAP group, but you can just give "user" if you want to.

[image]
  c) Retried login as my ID and LDAP password and **it worked**!!

d) **NOTE:** After the above LDAP settings, some users were able to login via their LDAP credentials (ex: userID 11223344) but few others couldn't (ex: userID hira12345). The users who couldn't login successfully  had different User base DN values different than the one who were able to login successfully.  To fix that, I had to change the `User Base DN` value to exclude the first 2 top level `OU=..` values, there after I added the following configuration (as shown below - image screenshot); Now, all users are now able to successfully log in.

You can **also** tweak the value inside `Group Base DN` field, to keep only 'DC=xxx,DC=yyy' i.e. set a more common search path (set inside LDAP for  most of the users (employees/contractors/etc) in your company).

That way, Splunk's LDAP configuration for `'mapping'` a group, will list **more** `LDAP Group Names`.

You can find that information by running the following `ldapsearch` command, to find what's that common value for every user id. Look for lines which contains `memberOf:` or `dn:` or `distinguishedName:`. The **most important** one is `memberOf:`.

Ex: `ldapsearch` command, where `$p` contains the password for CN=..user.. listed below. You can keep any level, sub-level in the command below acc. to your needs.

```
ldapsearch -D "CN=someServiceAccountAuthenticationUser,OU=Admin_Account,OU=Users,OU=top1,DC=level1,DC=level2,DC=level3" -w $p -p 389 -h myldap-server-ld01  -b "DC=level1,DC=level2,DC=level3" -s sub "put_a_valid_ldap_userID_here"
```

[image]

Comment: Arun, As this solution worked, you can mark your answer as accepted. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Hope this helps!